# Python Getting string from text file, and checking if there's matched word in the text file

Tags: python, regex

None of my tried attempts were succeed, i tried to change the lines, change the text file lines. What I'm doing here, is trying to search for the name, which user puts inside input("Whats your name?"), and if the system founds the name in the text file, it prints a message. 
Screenshot of the code, and CMD.

```
# Atidarom text'ini faila, kuriam visi ban nickai
Banlistas = open('Listas_BAN.txt', mode='r').readlines()
name = input("~ Please enter Your name below\n")
clear()
# Checking if there's name in the BANLIST Which is currently in Listas_BAN
if name in Banlistas:
    print('your name {n} is in the list'.format(n=name))
else:
    print('your name {n}, was not found in the list'.format(n=name))
```

The system is not finding the name, but it is in the text file.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEXdJ.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwdae.png)

P.S - Sorry for my English, I'm also new to python

EDIT :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzVfr.png)

Comment: Folks aren't going to follow links in a question. I recommend printing the name to check that it is exactly as you think it is. You might also want to make sure you're not having a case-sensitive issue, like if they type "john" and the list contains "John", you'll want to account for that.

Comment: I've updated the pictures, i uploaded them here

Comment: what you are doing is checking in a list and if there is not an exact match it will not work.

Comment: What you are checking for is a list match and unless it is an exact match it will not work. for example ["Raulis,\n", .. ,.. ,..] the first element of the list Banlistas is for example "Raulis,\n" note the , and the newline character , hence when you check for "Raulis" and check if it exists in the file, you will receive a boolean negative. Fix this issue and your problem will be solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name = input("~ Please enter Your name below\n")
ban_path = 'Listas_BAN.txt' # be sure to replace by the full path

with open(ban_path , mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    if name in f.read():
        print('your name {n} is in the list'.format(n=name))
    else:
        print('your name {n}, was not found in the list'.format(n=name))
```

A few things here:

- you should use the `with` keyword to open your file: it will take care of the opening/closing of your file
- adding the encoding could be helpful to manage special characters
- `f.read()` will return the full content of the file, no need to iterate over the lines

Comment: Thanks :) Appreciate your help

Comment: Can i also get a bit of explanation of this code - with open(ban_path, mode='r', encoding='utf-8') as f: I would like to also Learn not only Copy paste.

Comment: Also after this code, when I tried on other nicks, the system won't find em. I uploaded Screenshot to thread

Comment: About the `with` keyword, you could look there: [python-with-statement](http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm)

Comment: The encoding option let you force which encoding the reader should use to read your file (it may be another encoding, but utf-8 is the most usual). More about encoding tehre: [encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x](https://www.pythoncentral.io/encoding-and-decoding-strings-in-python-3-x/)

Comment: The code I proposed only looks for one nickname at a time, if you want to search many comma separated nicknames, you should either use the `split()` method on the input or use a regex